# Why do we put '(' before fucntion in JS?

Tags: javascript

Why do we have ( before function word here?

```
(function() {

     var message = "Привет"; function showMessage() {
    alert( message );   }

     showMessage();

})();
```

Comment: to make it an inline function expression from function declaration so that you can immediately invoke it.

Comment: To enclose the function into it's own closure, all variables defined with in it will not have conflict with other global variables

Comment: @AdamAzad: That's what the function is for, not the `(` before it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, what about `( /* code */ )()`?

Comment: @AdamAzad: What about it? Unless you put a function expression where `/* code */` is, no scope is created, and that will fail with an error.

Comment: Re closing as duplicate: Although the earlier question asks about `+`, the answers there answer this question (which is the dupe test on SO).

Comment: @AdamAzad Parentheses do not create scopes. Only braces do.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 And in ES5 and earlier, only *functions* do.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to:

```
function() { return 1; }()
```

then you will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

JavaScript parser runs in two modes, lets call it expression mode and normal mode, in normal mode JS parser expects top level declarations like functions and code blocks. You use '(' to enter expression mode, in expression mode `function() { }` will be interpreted as constant whose value is a function.

There is similar case with objects literals:

```
{ foo: 1 }
```

without '(' this means block of code, where you have single expression - constant 1 proceeded by label, when you use `({ foo: 1 })` parser enters expression mode and interprets it as object literal with property `foo`.

Why two modes, it is enforced by language grammar which in case of JS is pretty complicated (like in most C based languages).